# Angular 8 : using mat-tree with NgRx

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngrx

I've started an app with Angular 8 with some [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/) few weeks ago while I am a noob on the framework ... but I love challenges !

One of the App most interesting feature is to display a tree, and dynamically find the next nodes when user clicks on one of them, by fetching them from a distant API.

Currently, I have succeeded to manage my global store with NgRx, using effects to make request, dispatch correct actions, setup the reducers, create my selectors... I also followed the [Tree with Dynamic Data example](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples) from Angular Material, but I don't really know the pattern used by the example

Here is my code that manages store + request

```js
// movies.actions.ts
export const MOVIES_ACTIONS_REQUEST_CHILDREN = 'movies/REQUEST_CHILDREN';
export const MOVIES_ACTIONS_REQUEST_CHILDREN_SUCCESS = 'movies/REQUEST_CHILDREN_SUCCESS';
export const MOVIES_ACTIONS_REQUEST_CHILDREN_ERROR = 'movies/REQUEST_CHILDREN_ERROR';

export class GetMovieChildren extends IAction {
  public static readonly type: string = MOVIES_ACTIONS_REQUEST_CHILDREN;

  constructor(
    public parentId: number,
  ) {
    super();
  }
}

export class getMoviesChildrenSuccess extends IAction {
  public static readonly type: string = MOVIES_ACTIONS_REQUEST_CHILDREN_SUCCESS;

  constructor(
    public children: Array<any>,
  ) {
    super();
  }
}

export class getMoviesChildrenError extends IAction {
  public static readonly type: string = MOVIES_ACTIONS_REQUEST_CHILDREN_ERROR;

  constructor(
    public error: any,
  ) {
    super();
  }
}

// movies.effects.ts
@Effect()
public getMoviesChildren$: Observable<IAction> = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(MOVIES_ACTIONS_REQUEST_CHILDREN),
  mergeMap((action) => {
    return this.movieService.getMoviesChildren(action.parentId)
    .pipe(
      map(children => new getMoviesChildrenSuccess(children),
      catchError(error => of(new getMoviesChildrenError(error))),
    );
  }),
);

// movies.services.ts
public getMoviesChildren(parentId: string): Observable<Array<any>> {
  return this.request.get(`http://localhost:9000/movies/${parentId}/children`)
  .pipe(
    map(formatResponseToJSON),
    catchError(errorHandle),
  );
}

// movies.reducer.ts
/** Should I manage a movies tree or an set of nodes in the reducer ? **/
```

I just want to plug this code with [this one](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples) (Tree with Dynamic Data Section) to allow an async load of children when user clicks on a node. Does someone have already experienced this case before and can help me on the steps to implement the async tree ? Is there a best practice about managing the tree (within NgRx Store ?)

Thanks you !
Juan

PS: I can put some code if needed

Comment: Hi Juan welcome to StackOverflow. Can you paste your code, or create a https://stackblitz.com/ for us to be able to help? Please remember to always include the relevant code you are working on.

Comment: Hey @FRECIA, thanks for the tip ! I am editing the post to make it better :)

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain a state of expanded (selected) nodes in your state, and fetch nodes you need to display (root and expanded) by the selector.
Then you can implement DataSource which utilize that selector to provide data to tree component. Something like this:

```
export class DynamicDataSource implements DataSource<Node> {

    constructor(
        private store: Store<State>,
        private treeControl: FlatTreeControl<Node>)
    {
    }

    connect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): Observable<Node[] | readonly Node[]> {
        this.treeControl.expansionModel.changed.subscribe(change => 
            {
                if ((change as SelectionChange<Node>).added)
                {
                    this.store.dispatch(fromActions.expandNodes({ids: change.added.map(node => node.id)}))
                }
                if ((change as SelectionChange<Node>).removed) 
                {
                    this.store.dispatch(fromActions.collapseNodes({ids: change.added.map(node => node.id)}))
                }
            }
        );
        return this.store.pipe(select(selectRootAndExpandedNodes));
    }

    disconnect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): void {} 
}
```